# Java - How do I Retrieve Text from Website (Not Source)

Tags: java, bots

I want to use java to retrieve text from a website. I can easily get the source by doing: (Thank you random internet person who posted this somewhere else)

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLConnection;

    public class WebCrawler{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                URL google = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com");
                URLConnection yc = google.openConnection();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(inputLine);

                }
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

However this leaves me with the problem of some sites returning 403s. Is there a way of getting around this?

Very simply I was hoping to use java to create a simple bot that would scan a forum thread and automatically respond based of user queries. Am I able to do this in java? or do I need to look at it from the perspective of another language/ data retrieval method?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I have an understanding of java syntax... but am rather new to all the libraries and abilities it possesses. This may be easy to do with custom libraries. However my searching hasn't allowed me to find any... or at least any that inform me how to install them.

Comment: If people wan't more information as to the actual use of this bot, its simply to scan a 4chan thread to play risk. I have seen others create it, but I can't get any of them to point me in the right direction.

Comment: `new URL("http://stackoverflow.com");`  For SO and other sites that support it, you'd be better off implementing an RSS feed reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done in Java. In theory, anything a web browser can do, Java can do - since, in the very worst case, you could write a web browser in Java.

A 403 is a "forbidden" response. You may need to set a particular `User-Agent` header, or the site might require HTTP basic authentication. Or perhaps it's rate-limiting you and you need to see about obeying their `robots.txt` rules...

Java is certainly not (in my opinion) the *easiest* language in which to write this type of code, but you're on a decent track here.

As for your "not source" in the title - the source of a web page is its text. If you download the page, you're going to get HTML; it's up to you to parse out what you need and discard the dross.

Comment: +1.  Not sure what "on decent track" means in relation to "bot.. scan a forum thread and automatically respond..." :)

Comment: I don't mind getting the HTML. but I just wanted to specify that my initial attempt to get the source was thwarted by the 403 and I didn't want someone to come in and tell me the part I already knew.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm a programmer, not a philosopher. The code is neither good nor evil and I don't dowse for intent.

Comment: How would I check which user-Agent I need, or what their robots.txt rules are? I doubt its something a simple google would turn up.

Comment: @user1179554 `robots.txt` is a standard, just go to `http://[THE URL]/robots.txt`. As for the `User-Agent`, they're trying to keep you off their site; make sure you're not breaking the terms of service (it would actually be electronic trespass if you were) and then take the agent string from a "normal" browser like Internet Explorer.

Comment: @Borealid I found the robots.txt file. It states which User-Agents it disallows. One of which is:

User-agent: *
Disallow: /

Does this imply that All user-agents are disallowed? Also, as far as I can tell this bot does not break the ToS. I am pretty sure it doesn't mean all of them, as I can access the source code using chrome.

Comment: @user1179554 Only automated clients (bots) pay attention to `robots.txt`. So they've implied that they don't want any bots on their site.

Answer (score 1):

You may be getting 403's because you aren't changing your user-agent (Java) and the sites are responding to your bot by blocking it. If you change your user-agent var you could get in but that wouldn't be very ethical as these sites have blocked java user-agents for a reason.